# How to read car charger input current specification?

Tags: charger

I found two MacBook 60 Watts car chargers, one says on the backside “INPUT: 12V-24VDC 5.6A MAX”, the other “Input: DC 11-15V Max 10A”. So, the latter has an efficiency of 50%?

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/619ISd6fcKL.*SL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/619ISd6fcKL._SL1500_.jpg)

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61qLRTluyUL.*SL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61qLRTluyUL._SL1500_.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic, but those are just differences of voltage and current ranges. You have to check if your device (macbook) requirements fit these ranges.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to read the description different:

#1) Input 12-24V means it is capable for normal cars (12-14V) and Trucks (24V) and the 5.6A Max. is most likely the maximum allowed current before the internal fuse blows off.

#2) Input 11-15V means it is only usable for cars (no Trucks) and a maximum current of 10A before the internal fuse blows off.

so ... they are both usable for your need unless you own a Truck, then you should take #1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **passenger vehicle** either charger will work.  If you are using a **specializied commercial, industry, or military vehicle** that works on a 24volt system (you will know if it does or not) then the first adapter is the one that you need to use.

*However...*

**I would not use either of these.**  3rd party power adapters are notorious for being of poor quality and could be dangerous to not just your Mac, but to you as well.  If this is for your car, I recommend getting  a [DC power inverter](http://amzn.to/1RxfFOP) and a [GENUINE Apple Power Adapter](http://amzn.to/1puBAjm)

You are connecting an Apple laptop worth thousands to a $30 adapter....to me, it's just not worth the risk.  The second benefit is that you will have standard AC power outlets, meaning you can use them for just about anything you would plug into your home.